# How Do I Delete Previous Shared Memory Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

This piece of code works to create some shared memory.

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory    

def shared_memory_array(name_aditional, hight, width):
    _name = 'shm_' + name_aditional
    a = np.random.rand(hight, width)
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=_name, create=True, size=a.nbytes)
    return [_name, shm]
```

After coming out of a debugger or an error, it complains in subsequent runs.

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 100, in __init__
 self._fd = _posixshmem.shm_open(
 FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/shm_name'
```

How would I correctly check and delete shared memory from previous runs?

Answer (score 2):

so If someone comes across. As no solution here this workaround worked for me

```
def shared_memory_array(name_aditional, hight, width):
    _name = 'shm_' + name_aditional
    a = np.random.rand(hight, width)
    try:
        shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=_name, create=True, size=a.nbytes)
        return [_name, shm]
    except FileExistsError:
        shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=_name, create=False, size=a.nbytes)
        return [_name, shm]
    except Exception as shm_e:
        log('Error:' + str(shm_e))
        print('Error:' + str(shm_e))
        return ["Error", None]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing proper cleanup of the shared memory.  Since you set the flag `create=True`, the program is trying to create a new file named '/shm_name', but is failing because a file already exists.

You need to either set `create=False` when initializing SharedMemory on existing shared memory files or delete the shared memory file either manually or preferably via the `shm.unlink()` method, making sure to do this before trying to create a new file.

It is best practice to be using `shm.close()` to temporarily close a SharedMemory and `shm.unlink` to erase a SharedMemory when they are not active as it will improve performance and avoid memory leaks.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory.close

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak

Comment: `"After coming out of a debugger or an error"` I think you're missing this. OP seems to know all this but wants to know how to handle the cases where the `SharedMemory` was not freed due to an error or negligence.

Comment: thanks, Sure there is a close. But there can be a disaster around the program. The question is more about how would I properly restart if there is a failed close. @Axe319 I couldn't have said it better.

Answer (score 1):

If you can open an interactive python REPL, you can attach to the lingering shared memory and unlink it properly from there. You'll need to know the name of the shared memory, though.

```py
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

name = 'foo' # replace this with the name of your lingering shared memory

shm = SharedMemory(name, create=False)

shm.unlink() # this closes all attachments to the memory and destroys it
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  It looks promising. However as you saw I found a solution two years ago which works from inside the program

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I wanted to add this answer for those who prefer cleaning up this memory without altering their app.